# Passing URL parameter to post request form in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When users click to apply for a certain job vacancy they are redirected to a form with the URL format:

```
.../jobs/{job}/create`
```

where {job} is the id.

I want to pass this id to the store function so that users can fill out the form, submit and all the data will be stored in the database, including the id that is passed. However, it does not seem to work and I get the following array_merge() error:

> array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, string given

This are the routes I use, one to redirect to the form page and the other to store the form submission:

```
Route::get('/jobs/{job}/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationsController@create');
Route::post('/applications', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationsController@store');
```

These are the functions in my controller

```
    public function create($job)
    {
        return view('applications/create', $job);
    }

    public function store(Request $request, $job)
    {
        $application = new \App\Models\Application;

        // Set object properties from the user input
        $application->job_id = $request->input($job);
        $application->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
        $application->message = $request->input('message');
        // Set default label (new)
        $application->label_id = "1";

        $application->save();

        return redirect('applications');
    }
```

And this is my form

```
    <div class="wrapper bg-light">
        <h1>Apply for job</h1>
        <form action="/applications" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <label for="message">Write a motivation letter</label>
            <br>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            <br><br>

            <label for="user_id">User id</label>
            <input type="number" name="user_id" id="user_id">
            <br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your URIs are all wrong here. If you're requesting a form to create an `Application`, your GET URI should reflect that. When sending the POST, the ID of the `Job` should be passed as a hidden form input and should absolutely not be in the URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably giving the error

```php
public function create($job)
{
    return view('applications/create', ['job' => $job]);

    //OR

    
    return view('applications/create', compact('job'));
}
```

And to pass back the `$job` to the store method, you can use a route param or a hidden input. Taking the route param way

Route definitions can be

```php
Route::post('/applications/{job}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationsController@store')->name('applications');
```

And you can modify the code for form

```
<div class="wrapper bg-light">
    <h1>Apply for job</h1>
    <form action="{{ route('applications', ['job' => $job]) }}" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <label for="message">Write a motivation letter</label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <br><br>

        <label for="user_id">User id</label>
        <input type="number" name="user_id" id="user_id">
        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Then in the store method you can access the value for `$job`

```php
public function store(Request $request, $job)
{
    //You can also get the value for $job via $request->route('job');

    $application = new \App\Models\Application;

    // Set object properties from the user input
    $application->job_id = $request->route('job');
    $application->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $application->message = $request->input('message');
    // Set default label (new)
    $application->label_id = "1";

    $application->save();

    //This redirect should be some other get route else it will keep error out
    //or keep submitting the form
    return redirect('applications');
}
```

**Update**

An easy alternative would be have a hidden input in the form which will pass back the value of `$job`

```
<div class="wrapper bg-light">
    <h1>Apply for job</h1>
    <form action="/applications" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <input name="job" value="{{ $job }}" type="hidden" />

        <label for="message">Write a motivation letter</label>
        <br>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <br><br>

        <label for="user_id">User id</label>
        <input type="number" name="user_id" id="user_id">
        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

The route can remain without a route param

```php
Route::post('/applications', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationsController@store')->name('applications');
```

And in the controller nothing changes if you are using `$request->job` to get the value

Comment: It works perfectly now, thank you so much! The only other thing is, like the other answers say, I had to change $application->job_id = $request->route($job) to just $application->job_id = $request->$job

Comment: Sorry my bad, it should have been `$request->route('job')` however `$request->job` also works. I like to write it as `$request->route('job')` so that it's very clear that this value is obtained from route param

Comment: From a semantic URI perspective, it makes no sense to have this value in the URI at all. It should just be passed as a hidden form input.

Comment: @miken32 From semantic URI perspective, the route url should be something like `/jobs/{job}/applications` I guess. And mentioned hidden input as an alternative which would be a better alternative with route url defined here

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in line

```
return view('applications/create', $job);
```

Change it to

```
return view('applications/create', ['job'=>$job]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The other answer was a little more in-depth so I marked that one as solved, but I appreciate your help greatly :)